# ¿Cómo llenar un Array de Imágenes?

Tags: array, qt, imagen, url, qml

Actualmente trabajo en **qml** y estoy utilizando un *array* donde guardo las rutas de mis imágenes:

```
property var imageList: [
    "Imagenes/Image1.png", "Imagenes/Image2.png", ... "Imagenes/Image10.png"
]
```

... pero ahora quiero utilizar un *FolderListModel*

```
FolderListModel {
    id:foldermodel
    folder: "file:/home/Documentos/proyectoN/Imagenes/"    
}
```

para que pueda reconocer cualquier carpeta en cualquier ubicación y obviamente su contenido (imágenes).
El detalle es que no se cómo acceder a cada archivo de dicha carpeta y traer la ruta de cada uno para seguirlas guardando en mi *Array*: (*imageList []* ).

Esas imágenes posteriormente son mostradas en un *Item* dinámicamente.

Espero me puedan ayudar, o si tienen alguna otra idea será gratamente aceptada.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soy el que realizó la pregunta anterior y encontré una solución a ella:

Pues bien, yo tenía un array donde almacenaba las rutas de mis imágenes:

```
property var imageList: [
    "Imagenes/Image1.png", "Imagenes/Image2.png", ... "Imagenes/Image10.png"
]
```

Pero quería utilizar un *FolderListModel* para que me reconociera cualquier carpeta que yo asignara, y así poder acceder a los archivos (imágenes) de la misma y poder mandarlos a mostrar.

Lo que hice fue implementar bien mi *FolderListModel* de la siguiente manera:

```
FolderListModel {
        id: foldermodel
        folder: "file:/home/Documentos/proyectoN/Imagenes/"

        property string source

        onFolderChanged:  {
            for(var i = 1; i < foldermodel.count; i++){
                source = get(i,"fileName")           
                imageList.push(folder + "/" + source )                    
            }
        }
    }
```

donde indico que se van a recorrer todos los archivos de dicha carpeta y  mandar a traer el nombre de cada archivo por medio del método *get (index, **string** property)* y almacenarlos en la variable *source*, y una vez que trae el nombre, se concatena la ruta del folder **más** el nombre del archivo para que se vayan insertando a mi array *imageList*.

No se les olvide que el método *get(**int** index, **string** property)* trae la propiedad que según tú asignes de acuerdo al índice que corresponde al archivo dentro de tu carpeta, en éste caso se utiliza: **"filename"** para traer el nombre del archivo, pero es importante indicar que es un *string*, yo lo hice fácil y dentro del parámetro del método pongo mi propiedad pero indicando que es una cadena: **"fileName"** si no marcará error y les dirá que hay una variable sin inicializar.

```
source = get(i, "fileName")
```

Ya al final tendrán un *array* con las rutas de cada imágen según su **folder** y ya lo podrán manipular como uds. deseen.
Gracias. Espero les sirva.

Answer (score 0):

```
"file:/home/Documentos/proyectoN/".arg(imageList[0]);
```

Concatena el elemento de tu array a una ruta estática, no dinámica, cuando lo mandes a llamar estarás obligando a que recorra toda la ruta.